# Get gridview data to datatable from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview on my page where I try to save data to datatable; the Id column and 2nd last column in gridiview are hidden;Also the last column is linkbutton(ItemTemplate) for Viewing Gridview row details.Now how can I save only the viewable gridview to datatable.
Please, help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the concept of list string here

For example:

```
    list<string>id=new list<string>();
    list<string>name=new list<string>();

    foreach(gridviewrows gv in gv.rows)
    {
        //write code for gridview cell values 
        id.add(gv column name);
        name.add(gv column name);
    }
```

Simply give id and name in insert statement

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You mean save to database I guess. Because DataTable is temporary data. Here is a collection about [everything you can do with gridview](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhW1NryGv6LxX4U4b07T4RlI), and here you can [watch how to save gridview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZIOI136IKY&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW1NryGv6LxX4U4b07T4RlI&index=24).